# Neta Revai is achzareyos?

Tags: animals, shiluach-haken, orla-revai

The Chizkuni 22:6 explains that taking the mother bird with its young ones would be cruel. He also lists cooking a kid in the milk of its mother,and slaughtering a mother with its calf on the same day. All these examples he lists as something that is cruel ,but then he lists netai rivai (bringing up fruit to Jerusalem in its 4th year of growth or redeeming it on a coin) as cruel. How is netai revai included as something which may be cruel?

Text of Chizkuni:

לא תקח האם על הבנים לפי שהוא דרך אכזריות ורעבתנות וכן גדי בחלב אמו וכן אותו ואת בנו וכן נטע רבעי.

Comment: Disagrees with Yad Hachazaka.

Answer (score 8):

My understanding is that Chizkuni's focus when bringing *neta' reva’i* into the discussion is *ra'avtanut* i.e. voracity or gluttony.

He is saying that a reason behind forbidding eating very immature animals together with or in the presence of their parents (*shiluach haken*, *g'di bachaleiv imo*, *oto v'et b'no*) is to teach us to curb our appetites and make us wait before we can consume something.

The same is true of *orlah* and *neta' reva'i*: we must wait before we can consume the produce of our fruit trees, not eating any of it in the first three years and waiting until we can bring the fruit to Jerusalem in the fourth.

Comment: I initially understood like the OP. Then I reread it and understood like you ;-)